# JavaScript / JSON - Access array element using a key name as index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord

I want to be able to access an array element by using a unique key name instead of a numeric index. In my situation, I'm making a Discord bot and each servers have their own settings. When someone sends a message on a server, I want to access some of this server's settings (such as a message prefix). IMPORTANT: Right now, the only way I can do this is looping through all the servers that the bot is in, which in long-term, could slow it down if there's hundreds of active servers sending messages. So looping through all the servers is already being done right now, but I want a direct way without having to do this.

conf.json:

```
{
    "Settings": [
         "358262452343013386" {
             "prefix": "$",
             "Admins": [
                 "155444308395294720"
             ],
             "NotificationChannel": "358772856282284033",
             "robotpieces": []
         }
    ]
}
```

What I want to be able to do in my bot.js:

```
console.log(conf.Settings[message.guild.id].prefix); // outputs the prefix
// message.guild.id is the id of the server, which in this case, would translate to this:
console.log(conf.Settings["358262452343013386"].prefix) // outputs '$'
```

Any ideas of how I can achieve a similar goal WITHOUT having to loop through all of the array?

EDIT:
I know the following JSON is invalid, but I want a solution which would give the same result.

Comment: That is invalid JSON.

Comment: Numeric indexes **are** unique key names. They are just key names that happen to be numbers.

Comment: you can use another data structure with key value pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that the JSON you posted is invalid, you could **store the server settings as an object rather than an array**, and access is just like you are trying to:

```
{
    "Settings": {
         "358262452343013386": {
             "prefix": "$",
             "Admins": [
                 "155444308395294720"
             ],
             "NotificationChannel": "358772856282284033",
             "robotpieces": []
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but how would I get the object in Javascript? using 

console.log(conf.Settings.message.guild.id); or even

var GuildID = message.guild.id;
console.log(conf.Settings.GuildID);
does not output the object, but 'undefined'

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, I found out I could use it this way:
console.log(conf.Settings[message.guild.id]);
Thanks man! :)